# How can I get mobile safari to use the right CSS?

Tags: html, css, mobile

I have 2 stylesheets. One is for general website and the other is for mobile.

CSS for browsing on PC:

```html
<link href="/context/resources/css/landing.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

CSS for mobile:

```html
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="only screen and (max-device-width:480px)" href="/context/resources/css/mobile/landing.css" />
```

However, the mobile Safari on my iPhone4 *always* uses the PC `landing`.css file instead of the mobile version.

Any idea why and how I can fix it?

Comment: If the first link is in the html then this stylesheet will be included and parsed, why wouldn't it be?

Comment: OK. How do I make it either or?

Comment: I've had the two links switched place before and it still does not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your iPhone4, you'll need the high density piece as well:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="only screen and (max-device-width:480px) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)" href="/context/resources/css/mobile/landing.css" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the first line as the following:

```
<link href="/context/resources/css/landing.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

See also: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/media.html#media-types